# Is there a way to induce memory corruptions on Solaris platform manually?

Tags: testing, memory, automated-tests, solaris, memory-corruption

I need to test a new bit of code on Solaris 11. This code claims to work tolerating memory corruptions. I need to test that with no options in hand :(. Could someone please help me with this?

--Thanks

Comment: What language?  This might be possible in C or C++, but more difficult in managed languages.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, please note that the code I need to test is written in C and I am free to test the code in any language or using any tool. So any suggestions are helpful.